# $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms on $\mathbb{Q}(x_1, ..., x_n)$ map one-to-one into $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, symmetric-groups, splitting-field, automorphism-group

Let $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be a polynomial that doesn't have zeroes in $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\mathcal{N} \in \mathbb{C}$ be the set of zeroes of $p(x)$. How to prove that the map

\begin{align}
\mbox{Aut}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{Q}(\mathcal{N})) &\to S_n \\
\phi \mapsto \phi \vert_{\mathcal{N}}
\end{align}

is an injective group homomorphism?

The homomorphism part follows directly from the definition of the composition of functions, if I am not mistaken. But how to prove the injectivity part?

Comment: The automorphism is completely determined by what it does on $\mathcal{N}$, because every element of $\mathbb{Q}(\mathcal{N})$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-polynomial expression on $\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for our comment! I would be grateful if you could spell that out in more detail for me!

Comment: If $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$, and $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$, then $K(\alpha)\cong K[x]/(p(x))$. In particular, every element of $K(\alpha)$ can be written in the form $f(\alpha)$ for some $f(x)\in K[x]$. Since $K(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n) = K(\alpha_1)(\alpha_2)\cdots(\alpha_n)$, this tells you that every element of $K(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ can be written in the form $h(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$, where $h(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ when all the $\alpha_i$ are algebraic. In particular, knowing what $\phi$ does to the $\alpha_i$, determines it.